# PHP include using jquery AJAX from a dropdown select option?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to include an external php (on my own server) in another php page using `jQuery AJAX` from a `select form`.

basically I want to let the user include the `external php` file if they select `YES` option from the `dropdown select form` and remove it if they select `NO`.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
        $('#test2').change(function(){
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if (selectedValue === 'Yes') {
                $("#content").load("include.php");
            } else {
                //WHAT DO I NEED TO PUT HERE TO REMOVE THE "include.php" if it has been inlcluded?
            }
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select id="test2">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">No</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**First question:** am I doing this right?

**Second question:** what do I need to do in order to remove the `include.php` file if they select `NO option`?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. i do have jquery included in my page.

Comment: your code is correct.If user selects NO then nothing wil happen as you do nothing . So what is ur problem?Be confident dude.

Comment: Please include jquery library. It is missing in your code.

Comment: @loganphp ,he just gave sample html ,he is smart enough to include JS library . :) dnt scare him

Comment: @PratikJoshi, cheers mate.. yeah, I deffo need some confidence :).. but, would this code, remove the included php file if the user selects Yes first and then No?

Comment: First, does this `include.php` have anything to do with your current page? What does it do? Second, you cannot _exclude_ php the way you think. You need to explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, well in a way it has something to do with it and in a way it doesn't. lol so it would be difficult to explain what the php files do. my question is not about my php files. it was more of a question on how to clear the included php file the same way i included it.

Comment: why you clear php files ,Just clear html affected by it

Comment: Using load() to Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. You have many ways to remove content from that element using .html('') or empty().

Comment: @PratikJoshi, Yeah, that's what I meant... sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @user3454730 i asked because when you include php, it's going to just run the PHP code and load the output in your container and from the answers below, it's only going to clear the output that you have loaded in your container. Is that what you need?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, the `include.php` file has no output. its purely a server side script. so if the user views it in the browser, they get a white blank page. also, my `container div` has `display:none;` so it doesn't matter as long as the include.php runs once its loaded and gets removed (it doesn't run) once its been removed.

Comment: would love to know who it is behind the "downvote" and also the reason behind it?

Comment: @user3454730 If your PHP is not sending any output I see no reason to make your container empty. You cannot "undo" the changes made by PHP if that's what you mean, this is why I asked you to explain what you were trying to do.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, even though, I explained it, you still clearly don't understand the concept. the PHP code is above the HTML form. so without the php code in that page, the form won't do anything and once the php code is included, the form will do what it should do. I hope that makes sense now

Comment: @user3454730 It seems you are the one who doesn't understand. Do you think `load('page.php')` returns back all the PHP code within it? Try it and see.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, wasn't trying to disrespect mate. yeah, i don't really understand and that is why i asked this question and specifically mentioned AJAX as i know you can run php files using AJAX. WHAT i was referring to was that you didn't understand "my concept".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50873/discussion-between-i-can-has-cheezburger-and-user3454730)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If yes is selected then 
    Include file    
else
$( ".page" ).empty();
//make the page content empty Simple
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to make the whole page emtpy (and doesn't have anythign with a page class).  Only the #content div

Comment: @Adam, +1 For actually reading the question and understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

The `$('#comment').html('')` in the else block are right.  However, your if-condition is wrong (`.val()` returns the value not the text of the chosen option).  Use:

```
$('#test2').change(function(){
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if (1 == selectedValue) {
                $("#content").load("include.php");
            } else {
                $('#content').html('');
            }
        });
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet.. but this looks like what I am looking for. I will select this as the answer as soon as I've tried it.

Comment: @user3454730 ,hello i also gave u answer ,why not to select my ans?

Comment: @PratikJoshi, tried yours now.. and it worked as it should mate... nice one.

Comment: @PratikJoshi Please. First of all the class you are using is nowhere mentioned in the OP's code and like Adam said, the OP is not trying to make the page empty, only the container.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, Patrik is not showing how to empty the page!! he's actually giving a class `.class` so that could be an ID `#id` instead. it worked for me... I'm sure you haven't tried it and just going by what Adam said!!!

Comment: @user3454730 There's nothing to try in this. I'm not even sure what you are trying to do. You said your PHP does not output anything then why do you need your container to get empty? Makes absolute no sense.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger ,helo chij burgur , OP got what he had to get.Also .page class can be given to anything USer wants .Also Id can also be used instead of class ,no problem.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above.  I did not say that using .empty() was wrong.  However, to use a completely different class (`.page` when the OP uses `.content`) and then to have a comment "make the page content empty" was potentially confusing/misleading.  It's generally best to stick to the classes/elements in the OP code when giving an answer.  The rest was psuedo-code which did not address the other problem with the OP code (the if-condition), so I posted my own answer.  @Pratik Joshi's code can be adapated to work but needs adapting

Comment: @Adam, I 100% agree with you. I have been confused countless times when someone changes the class or id in their answer. but in this instance, I understood it and it worked for me. I wish i could select 2 answers. i did +1 your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it's requesting include.php just fine.
You can clear the loaded data by calling

```
$('#content').html('');
```

in the `else` section

Comment: Or by calling `.empty()`

Comment: Actually `empty()` would be better yeah. Thanks